# Backbone Router navigate and anchor href

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In a backbone-enabled app, I have seen code that continues to use `<a href="#foo"></a>`, while the anchor click is handled by a backbone event handler.

Alternatively, the navigation to #foo can be handled by:

```
Router.history.navigate("foo");
```

I believe the latter is the superior approach because it allows easy migration to and from HTML5's pushState functionality. And if we do use pushState, Backbone would be able to gracefully degrade to #foo for browsers that do not support pushState.

As I am still new to Backbone, can someone more experienced and knowledgable confirm that this is the case?

Comment: Check out this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799977/how-to-apply-backbone-router-for-full-path-not-a-hash

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I personally have `pushState` enabled and use the approach taken in Tim Branyen's backbone-boilerplate of [adding a click handler](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate/blob/master/app/main.js#L22) that sends all link clicks to `navigate` unless they have a `data-bypass` attribute:

```
$(document).on("click", "a:not([data-bypass])", function(evt) {
  var href = { prop: $(this).prop("href"), attr: $(this).attr("href") };
  var root = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + Backbone.history.options.root;

  if (href.prop && href.prop.slice(0, root.length) === root) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    Backbone.history.navigate(href.attr, true);
  }
});
```

This works pretty well and as @nickf mentions has the advantage that you don't have to use the hash/hashbang hack, even for browsers that do not support pushState.

Comment: Excellent response; thanks. I especially appreciate the github reference, which I just read. Not sure how, but I kind of wish this is boilerplate code I don't have to write.

Comment: If you change 'app.root' to 'Backbone.history.options.root', then it'll work where 'app' isn't in the current context.

Answer (score 6):

You should write your links as their "proper" addresses, that is, not with the hash which is just a hack to get around some deficiencies of a particular browser. To then make it all work, attach a click handler to catch clicks on these items and pass the urls to Backbone.history, which can then use pushState or convert to a hashbang'd url if needed. For example:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="/"]', function (event) {
    // here, ensure that it was a left-mouse-button click. middle click should be
    // allowed to pass through
    event.preventDefault();
    Backbone.history.navigate(this.href);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Chris' answer is awesome, but there's one addition to it that makes it even better. `Backbone.history.navigate()` actually returns true or false telling us if it could route to it internally. We can therefore skip the `data-bypass` attribute and do the following instead:

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function(evt) {
  var href = { prop: $(this).prop("href"), attr: $(this).attr("href") };
  var root = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + Backbone.history.options.root;

  if (href.prop && href.prop.slice(0, root.length) === root) {
    if (Backbone.history.navigate(href.attr, true)) {
      evt.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes I try to use as much Router.history.navigate as I can in my Backbone apps. This also has the benefit of if the user types in the URL "/foo" in their browser, Backbone routes it properly. Obviously if it is an external link or something you don't want to handle with Backbone then you should not include it.