# pushState preventing Backbone.js routes from working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, pushstate

I'm having an issue with HTML5 pushState in a RequireJS/Backbone.js app, I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong but I can't identify the problem, I've tried for hours.

Foreword: All of the RequireJS dependencies are in their correct folders.

Here's my issue: I have a basic little setup - the only Backbone component I'm using is the router. On the default '' route, I call a 'home' method in the router. This method does nothing more than alert "Test", and it works.

However, once I add `{pushState: true}` as a parameter to `Backbone.history.start()` in the top-level `app.js` file, the 'home' method is no longer being called.

These are the blocks of code in which it is happening:

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Todo</title>
    <script data-main="assets/js/app/app.js" src="assets/js/app/lib/require.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: 'assets/js/app',
  paths: {
    'underscore': 'lib/underscore',
    'jquery': 'lib/jquery',
    'backbone': 'lib/backbone',
    'text': 'lib/text',
    'handlebars': 'lib/handlebars',
    'router': 'router/router'
  },
  shim: {
    'underscore': {
      exports: '_'
    },
    'backbone': {
      deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    }
  }
});
require(['router', 'backbone'], function(Router, Backbone) {
  var router = new Router();
  Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });
});
```

router.js:

```
define(['backbone'], function(Backbone) {
  var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      '': 'home'
    },
    home: function() {
      alert('test');
    }
  });
  return Router;
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this an incorrect, convoluted approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with a solution to my own problem, funny that.

The issue with implementing pushState is that for any route to work, even the default home route, a back-end server is needed to initially render the page so that Backbone can then fire the correct JavaScript after checking the route.

This means that developing a local instance and navigating to it using the `file://` protocol will not work. (Which is what I made the mistake of doing in the above question).

For this simple use case, I coded up a simple ExpressJS server that serves an **index.jade** view (I removed the index.html) when it encounters *any* **wildcard** route, and that then allows Backbone to correctly render the routes with this tiny snippet of code:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
}
```

However, it is *imperative* that further changes are made should you wish to support search engine crawling, and those changes involve having route-specific server-side versions of your views that your server can render in case a route is directly accessed. If you do not wish to support SEO crawlability, for example in the case of a web application that requires users to be logged in,  then re-routing **all** routes through a single rendered file is fine. Backbone is smart enough to detect the remaining route paths to render the appropriate view. This is stated in [the Backbone documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#History)

> Note that using real URLs requires your web server to be able to correctly render those pages, so back-end changes are required as well. For example, if you have a route of /documents/100, your web server must be able to serve that page, if the browser visits that URL directly. For full search-engine crawlability, it's best to have the server generate the complete HTML for the page ... but if it's a web application, just rendering the same content you would have for the root URL, and filling in the rest with Backbone Views and JavaScript works fine.

**NOTE:** Using pushState can have an implication on how anchor tags (`<a href='/route'>`) work, as, by default, they will still try to "refresh" the page to fetch the matching route. Backbone's Router offers a `navigate` method that, when combined with a click event handler, allows you to bypass this default behaviour. [shioyama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/820254/shioyama) has posted an example of such an event handler as an answer to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081894/backbone-router-navigate-and-anchor-href)

The full code changes:

**/app.js**

```
var
express = require('express'),
app = express();

app.configure(function() {
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));
  app.use(app.router);
  app.locals.pretty = true;
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

app.listen(3030, function() {
  console.log("Listening on 3030");
});
```

**/assets/js/app/app.js**

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: '/js/app',
  paths: {
    'underscore': 'lib/underscore',
    'jquery': 'lib/jquery',
    'backbone': 'lib/backbone',
    'text': 'lib/text',
    'handlebars': 'lib/handlebars',
    'router': 'router/router'
  },
  shim: {
    'underscore': {
      exports: '_'
    },
    'backbone': {
      deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    }
  }
});
require(['router', 'backbone'], function(Router, Backbone) {
  var router = new Router();
  Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
});
```

**/assets/js/app/router/router.js**

```
define(['backbone', 'jquery'], function(Backbone, $) {
  var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      '': 'home',
      'fred': 'fred'
    },
    home: function() {
      $('#main').append('<p>This is the <strong>HOME</strong> route.');
    },
    fred: function() {
      $('#main').append('<p>This is the <strong>FRED</strong> route.');
    }
  });
  return Router;
});
```

**/views/index.jade**

```
!!!
html
  head
    title Todo
    script(data-main='/js/app/app.js', src='/js/app/lib/require.js')
  body
    #main
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue trying to figure out why my Backbone learning projects all work, but the basic boilerplate from Chaplin didnt. They opt to pushState: true when they construct the router.

Figuring out why thats desirable is probably another couple of hours of reading, but i really like the simplicity of having all my files on file:// url without any server, especially when my code needs to be portable in things like PhoneGap

Comment: Haven't had a try at Chaplin yet, but I'm sure you could override that, couldn't you?

Comment: Yes easily done, AFTER an a long time stepping through the code trying to figure out whats going on. Well, at least a good learning excercise.