# Backbone Router routes not firing with href link

Tags: html, backbone.js, href, backbone-routing

Root problem: 
Backbone routes not firing when a hyperlink is clicked. Instead I get a 404 because instead of calling the backbone route, there is a server send request.

[image]

Here's the link in html ("testLink"):

```
<script id="header1" type="text/template">
<table id="headerTable">
    <tr>
        <td id="headerCol1"><button id="playlistBtn"><div class="glyphicon glyphicon-music crimson"></div></button><span id="numberOfSongs" class="badge badge-notify crimson"></span></td>
        <td id="headerCol2"></td>
        <td id="headerCol3" align="right">
            <div id="dropDownMenu" class="dropdown" data-theme="b">
                <button id="menuButton" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><p><span id="currentUser" class="crimson"></span><span class="caret crimson"></span></p></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" data-theme="b">   
                  <li id="testBtn"><a href="testLink">Test Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've tried many variations including:

href="#testLink", resulted in no url update, nothing happened

href="#/testLink", same as above nothing happened

href="/#/testLink", same as above nothing happened

href="/testLink", resulted in 404 with a send request to the server

href="testLink", same as above, 404 with send request to server (this was my first choice)

Here's my router code:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

        routes: {
            "Profile":  "profilePage",
            "testLink": "test"
        },
        profilePage:function(){
            alert('You have navigated to the profile page');
        },
        test:function(){
            alert('testing this link');
        }
});
// Instantiate the router and start the history
var appRouter = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

I've tried variations of setting pushState to true, and setting the root option to '/' with no change in behavior.

Comment: Try using Backbone router [navigate](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate) with _trigger_ option to _true_ in the onclick callback instead of the href attribute.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081894/backbone-router-navigate-and-anchor-href) explains a good approach.

Comment: Thanks @FedericoBaron! The answer in your second comment was spot on. Creating the onclick handler and then setting the pushState:true in the router did the trick.